# I am trying to find unallocated time from specified time slot using MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Let say reserved time slot is

09:00 - 10:00

Following are the request reservation:

1) 08:00 - 09:15

For this request,result should show 08:00 - 09:00

2) 09:00 - 10:00

For this request,result should show 00:00 - 00:00

3) 09:45 - 10:45

For this request,result should show 10:00 - 10:45

4) 10:00 - 11:00

For this request,result should show 10:00 - 11:00

I am trying with following query but it does not give  proper result:

```
SELECT 
  CASE

    WHEN  time_from > p_in_time  THEN
    p_in_time
    WHEN  time_to <= p_in_time  THEN
    p_in_time

    ELSE '00:00:00' 
  END AS slot_in_time,
  CASE

    WHEN  time_from >= p_out_time  THEN 
      time_from
    WHEN   .time_to <= p_out_time  THEN
       p_out_time
    ELSE '00:00:00' 
  END AS slot_out_time 
FROM
  tbl_reserved_time
```

Any help will be great help for me.

---

@shadow  Thanks for your response:I try with following query:                             SELECT 
  CASE

```
WHEN  start_time > @p_in_time  THEN
@p_in_time
WHEN  end_time <= @p_in_time  THEN
@p_in_time


ELSE '00:00:00'
```

END AS slot_in_time,
  CASE

```
WHEN  end_time >= @p_out_time  THEN 
  start_time
WHEN   end_time <= @p_out_time  THEN
   @p_out_time
ELSE '00:00:00'
```

END AS slot_out_time 
FROM
  tbl_reserved_time

It works only for 1 condition (08:00-09:15)

Comment: Pls provide a detailed description as to what's wrong with your query, do not ask us to figure that out ourselves. For example, you could describe what your query produces for the sample cases you provided as opposed to what it should.

Answer (score 0):

I solved with :
select
  case

```
WHEN  start_time > @p_in_time   THEN
@p_in_time
WHEN  end_time <=  @p_in_time  THEN
@p_in_time
WHEN  end_time <=  @p_out_time  THEN
end_time


ELSE '00:00:00'
```

END AS slot_in_time,
  CASE
  WHEN  start_time > @p_in_time   THEN
    start_time

```
WHEN  end_time <=  @p_in_time  THEN
@p_out_time
WHEN  end_time <=  @p_out_time  THEN
@p_out_time


ELSE '00:00:00'
```

END AS slot_out_time 
FROM
  tbl_reserved_time